# Grep Command Line tool for Windows 8 and above

Tags: windows, grep

I have been looking through the different Grep tools for Windows but the recently updated ones are usually GUI (AstroGrep/grepWin) and the other common command line ones (GnuWin32/UnixUtils) doesn't seem to be able to run on my Windows 8.1 machine but runs perfectly fine on a Windows 7 VM.

So are there any command line grep tools avaliable for Windows 8.1 (besides findstr) or is using cygwin with the latest version of grep the only option?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is there anywhere on the stackoverflow family of sites that questions like this can be asked? I find pages like this very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PowerShell's [`Select-String`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx) on any W8+ machine!

```
Select-String .\*.* -pattern "needle"
```

[Source](http://dereknewton.com/2010/12/powershell-grep-equivalent/)

Here are [more example](https://communary.wordpress.com/2014/11/10/grep-the-powershell-way/) with `select-string` (`sls`).